# What does it mean to make note on sth?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean to make note on sth?
For example "to make note on my feelings"
Doese it mean to notice it or to make note of it?

I read this sentence in a presentation about Reiki Energy. The sentence is "make note on any thoughts or feelings that come to mind during your session."

Comment: I've never heard such an expression - where did you hear it?

Comment: More likely **to take note of**, which means to be aware/conscious of, to notice, Or, **to make a note of**....meaning to write it down or at least to make a conscious effort to remember it.

Comment: Thank for your answers. I read this sentence in a presentation about Reiki Energy. The sentence is "make note on any thoughts or feelings that come to mind during your session."

Answer (score 1):

This is an error in the original.  The proper expression is "make notes on".  It means "write down any thoughts or feelings in your notebook (so you can remember them later)"

Comment: Thanks a lot dear James K, that was so nice of you..